# How to check and remove if string in one column matches with string in another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe. 
Sample Data:

```
> df <- data.frame(MAKE = c('FORD','FORD','FORD','BMW','BMW'),
+                    MODEL = c('ECO SPORT','ECO SPORT','ECO SPORT','3 SERIES','5 SERIES'),
+                  VARIANT = c('ECOSPORT 1.0','ECOSPORT 1.5','ECOSPORT 1.5','E90','5 SERIES F(10)'),
                   stringsAsFactors = 0)
> 
> df
  MAKE     MODEL        VARIANT
1 FORD ECO SPORT   ECOSPORT 1.0
2 FORD ECO SPORT   ECOSPORT 1.5
3 FORD ECO SPORT   ECOSPORT 1.5
4  BMW  3 SERIES            E90
5  BMW  5 SERIES   5 SERIES F(10)
>
```

I need to find and remove the strings in "VARIANT" column that are there in "MODEL" column. I initially tried to identify the rows first using below command but it doesn't work.

```
> df[df$MODEL %in% df$VARIANT,]
[1] MAKE    MODEL   VARIANT
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
>
```

Could anyone let me know how to accomplish the same.
Expected Output:

```
> df
  MAKE     MODEL        VARIANT
1 FORD  ECO SPORT         1.0
2 FORD  ECO SPORT         1.5
3 FORD  ECO SPORT         1.5
4  BMW   3 SERIES         E90
5  BMW   5 SERIES         F(10)
>
```

Comment: `"ECO SPORT"` is not found in `"ECOSPORT"` (and vice versa). If you want fuzzy string matching or matching without whitespace, you should be more explicit. (They're both feasible, but have you determined how far you're intending to go to match similar strings?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)   
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(VARIANT  = str_remove_all(VARIANT,
              str_remove(MODEL, '(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z])')))
#  MAKE     MODEL VARIANT
#1 FORD ECO SPORT     1.0
#2 FORD ECO SPORT     1.5
#3 FORD ECO SPORT     1.5
#4  BMW  3 SERIES     E90
#5  BMW  5 SERIES   F(10)
```

Comment: This fails due to `factor`s (I'm on R-3.6, not sure if you or OP are on R-4.0 negating this concern) and does not detect `ECOSPORT` from `ECO SPORT`. I think OP needs to clarify a few things.

Comment: I am using R 4.0

Comment: Yes, have added stringsAsFactors to the question.

Comment: akrun it works, I am fairly new to regex, if it is possible, can you please tell what '(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z])' does.

Comment: @KarthikS it is based on the pattern I noticed in your post that except for the last row, where there is space between digit and letter, it needs to match as a whole or else we need to remove the space as in 'ECO SPORT'.  By doing the regex lookaround, it is telling to check for space that succeeds a letter and precedes another letter so that it won't match the space after the digit

Comment: Ok, Now I get it.